# How to add parent "wrapper" elements and validate them in existing schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have created a xml schema that validates my xml instances. Since I have been working on it for a while I have been commenting off little pieces of xml code at the time in order to simplify my learning of xml schema. I currently have a valid schema that has the following structure:

```
 <xsd:element name="singer" type="singerType"/> 
 <xsd:complexType name="singerType">
   <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="singer_id">
     ....
   ....
 ....
```

But now my xml file has this structure

```
<element1>
    <element2 id="1">
        <singer>
            <singer_id>
```

What I would like to do is to incorporate `element1` and `element2` into my existing schema. Both of these elements are complex types and I tried to do it in a few different ways but have been getting errors. Can someone point me in the right direction about how to add these 2 elements to my schema please?

Comment: How many `singer` elements are allowed inside `element2`? And what about `element1`? How many `element2` are allowed inside it? Also, can you show your full valid XSD, and one or more XML instances that should be validated by it?

Comment: there can be zero or more singers inside element2

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some assumptions here, since you didn't include enough code examples. If this doesn't answer your question, please edit your question adding more details.

You have a XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<element1 xmlns="http://your.target.namespace/singer"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://your.target.namespace/singer schema.xsd">
    <element2 id="1">
        <singer>
            <singer_id>123</singer_id>
        </singer>
        <singer>
            <singer_id>456</singer_id>
        </singer>
    </element2>
    <element2></element2>
    <element2>
        <singer>
            <singer_id>789</singer_id>
        </singer>
    </element2>
</element1>
```

You can validate it with this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://your.target.namespace/singer"
           xmlns="http://your.target.namespace/singer"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="singer" type="singerType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="singerType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="singer_id" type="xs:token" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="element1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="element2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element ref="singer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You might want to organize it differently, of course, exposing the complex types by name, if you intend to use them, or defining `element2` at the top level if you wish to use it elsewhere.